# How do you target particular UIViews when styling its UIAppearance?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am setting global styles in iOS 5 with [UIAppearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Here's an example:

```
[[UIbarButtonItem appearance]
    setTtitletextAttributes:someStyle
    forState:UIControlStateNormal
];
```

It looks good in most cases:

[image]

But there are cases where the global style looks ugly, like in a movie player.

[image]

For the movie player, I would prefer to have the default blue button. So how would I target only the back button's appearance and not the done button's appearance? I have similar issues with targeting normal table cells and grouped table cells.

Comment: Is there some way that you could just call +appearance before the player is shown and after it is dismissed?

Comment: You could try to create the UIBBarutton as a customView in that class so the UIAppearence proxy won't effect the styling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can actually change the proxy to just target certain view hierarchies. In other words, when the view you want to customize is contained in a certain view, you can modify its appearance differently from the rest. So set your global (white) style first, but then call the following method to customize the appearance for when the button appears in an `MPMoviePlayerController` or whatever else.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: 
      [MPMoviePlayerController class], nil] 
      setTitletextAttributes:someStyle
      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Fails with this message: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** MPMoviePlayerController does not conform to the UIAppearanceContainer protocol'

Comment: Fair enough. After looking at the documentation, I realize you have to use a class that actually conforms to the UIAppearanceContainer protocol, which is only UINavigationBar, UIButton, etc. But the same idea still applies

Comment: Except that you can't apply the idea to media players. See http://openradar.appspot.com/11296843.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a custom subclass of `UINavigationBar`.  Let's call it `MyNavigationBar`.  Then you can do this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationBar class], nil]
    setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

and it will only affect buttons within your navigation bar, not the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s navigation bar.

The problem, of course, is that `UINavigationController` always uses a basic `UINavigationBar`... if you create it in code.  But if you create it in a nib, you can click on its navigation bar (in the nib's document outline) and change the bar's class in the Identity inspector.

Comment: I don't use Interface Builder. How do I make all the `navigationBar`s throughout my app use my custom subclass? I did not explicitly `alloc` any `navigationBar`s.

Comment: As I said, “UINavigationController always uses a basic UINavigationBar if you create it in code.”. There is no public API to change this.  If you want to use my solution, you will need to get friendly with IB.  Don't worry, it doesn't bite.

Comment: This answer is correct and seems to be the only work-around. The original asker should mark this as the correct answer since Dylan's is wrong.

Comment: @JoJo Actually since iOS5 you can use initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass: to make standard UINavigationControllers use the bar class you specify

Answer (score 4):

If in your AppDelegate you just replace

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navback"]
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

with

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil]
 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navback"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

movie player will have proper black bar in full screen mode. Works in iOS 5 and iOS 6